# Convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^{\sqrt n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is the following series convergent or divergent?
>   $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^{\sqrt n}}$$

I find that both the [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) tests fail for this example. And I do not know what series I can use for the comparison test.

I would like to avoid the integral test. Could anyone help?

Comment: You mean $e^{\sqrt{n}}$?  This is eventually larger than any power of $n$, so feel free to use the comparison test.

Comment: To follow up on the first comment, you should be able to show that $3 \log x < \sqrt x$ for all $x > 0$, so that $$\frac 1{e^{\sqrt n}} \le \frac 1{n^3}$$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean $\sqrt n$ instead of $\sqrt k$, you can use

- $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Hence,

$$e^{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^6}{6!} = \frac{n^3}{6!}$$

It follows

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^{\sqrt n}} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\frac{n^3}{6!}} = 6!\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}< \infty$$

Comment: Nice one. +1$\,$

Answer (score 1):

We can write the sum as

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\,\sum_{m^2\le n<(m+1)^2}\frac{n}{e^{\sqrt n}}$$ $$< \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}((m+1)^2-m^2)\frac{(m+1)^2}{e^{m}} < \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)^4}{e^m},$$

and it's standard that the last series converges.

Comment: I think that your best bound is $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}((m+1)^2-m^2)\frac{(m+1)^2}{e^{m}}=\frac{-1+4 e-3 e^2+12 e^3}{(e-1)^4}\sim 26.2392$ while $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)^4}{e^m}=\frac{1-5 e+11 e^2+e^3+16 e^4}{(e-1)^5}\sim 64.2478$. In any mannner, very nice solution and $+1$. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a>1$, there is an integer $N>0$ so that $n>N\Rightarrow a^n>n^3.$

There are many ways to see this. You can note that, by L'Hospital, $\underset{x\to \infty}\lim\frac{a^x}{x^3}=\underset{x\to \infty}\lim\frac{(\ln a)^3a^x}{6}=\infty$

or that $a^n-n^3>\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n\ln a)^k}{k!}-n^3>-\frac{5n^3}{6}+\frac{(\ln a)^4n^4}{12}\to \infty$.

Now compare your series to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}.$

Comment: That's  a good one.